# What happened after the first video conference between Jason and Sarris?

Tags: plot-device, galaxy-quest

In *Galaxy Quest*, when the show's cast are taken to the spaceship by the Thermians the first time, Jason gets into a conference call with Sarris. At the end of the call, he off-handedly tells the aliens to shoot at Sarris' ship. The aliens seem to hesitate, but in the next scene they are shown thanking Jason for his help and happily send him back to Earth (at which point Jason finally realizes that he was on an actual spaceship).

I never got what actually happened here. He did tell the aliens to fire at Sarris' ship, which they presumably did. Sarris' ship was too strong for them to take out, so I don't think they were able to harm him in any way. After Jason reached back home, it looked like Sarris still hadn't destroyed the Thermians, and was still ready to negotiate with Jason for them to surrender.

I don't quite get what happened here. Could someone please summarize what happened during the first conference call between Jason and Sarris, and between the time Jason went home and came back to the ship the second time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per the [show script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/galaxyquest_trans.htm), Mathasar's crew fired on Sarris' ship, damaging it and causing Sarris personal injury. We can reasonably assume it took some time to recover from this.

> But he is interrupted by the sight of SARRIS appearing on the large VIEWSCREEN. Sarris now wears a metal eyepatch, and has a long scar across his cheek.
>
> **SARRIS:** *We meet again Commander.*
>
> The crew stares at Sarris. A frightening visage.
>
> **JASON:** *Hello Sarris... How are you doing?*
>
> **SARRIS:** *Better than my Lieutenant. He failed to activate the ship's neutron armor as quickly as I'd hoped on our last encounter*